# close all other element of a class while one is open

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a gallery page which requires each img element to have, a comment box attached to it.

Whenever I click the comment button the comment box pops up, but i'm having issues with closing any other opened comment boxes while i'm opening a new one.

In other word, i want only one element opened at a time.

I've tried so many javascript/jquery functions but doesn't seems to help, the last i tried will open all other comment boxes except the one with the button I clicked.

```js
$('body').on("click touchstart", ".openOne", function(e) {
    $('.chat-popup').toggle();
});

function openForm() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "block";
}
function closeForm() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "none";
}

function openForm1() {
  document.getElementById("myForm1").style.display = "block";
}
function closeForm1() {
  document.getElementById("myForm1").style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- html for form 1 and button 1 -->

<a title="Comment" class="lk-btn openOne" onclick="openForm()"> Comment</a>
<div class="chat-popup" id="myForm">
  <form name="commentForm" class="form-container">
    <div class="screen" class="screen"></div>
    <textarea id="myComment" class="input" placeholder="Type comment.." autofocus></textarea>
    <button id="submit" class="lk-btn openOne" 
        onclick="postComment(); clearText(); return false">Send</button>
    <button class="lk-btn openOne" 
        onclick="closeForm(); clearText(); return false">Close</button>
    <div id="commentBox" class="comment-box"></div>
  </form>
</div>

<!-- html for form 2 and button 2 -->

<a title="Comment" class="lk-btn openOne" onclick="openForm()"> Comment</a>

<div class="chat-popup" id="myForm">
  <form name="commentForm" class="form-container">
    <div class="screen" class="screen"></div>
    <textarea id="myComment" class="input" placeholder="Type comment.." autofocus></textarea>
    <button id="submit" class="lk-btn openOne" 
        onclick="postComment(); clearText(); return false">Send</button>
    <button class="lk-btn openOne" 
        onclick="closeForm1(); clearText(); return false">Close</button>
    <div id="commentBox" class="comment-box"></div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: put entire code here, where is `openForm23()` ?

Comment: please i don't know what else to put here, i've explained the problem the best way i can right now.

Comment: how look all your class ? (lk-btn , openOne , chat-popup , form-container , screen , comment-box ); why do you have empty elements ?  + in HTML **id must be unique**

Answer (score 0):

Just use one function for `openForm()` and address the one you want to open with an argument.

```
function openForm(number) {
  $('.chat-popup').css('display','none');
  $('#myform' + number).css('display','block');
}

function closeForm() {
  $('.chat-popup').css('display','none');
}
```

Your html should then start with `myForm1` then `myForm2` and so on

```
 <a title="Comment" class="lk-btn openOne" onclick="openForm()"> Comment</a>
    <div class="chat-popup" id="myForm1"> <!-- HERE THE CHANGE -->
      <form name="commentForm" class="form-container">
        <div class="screen" class="screen"></div>
        <textarea id="myComment" class="input" placeholder="Type comment.." autofocus></textarea>
        <button id="submit" class="lk-btn openOne" 
           onclick="postComment(); clearText(); return false">Send</button>
        <button class="lk-btn openOne" 
           onclick="closeForm(); clearText(); return false">Close</button>
        <div id="commentBox" class="comment-box"></div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

There is no need to generate a function for each of your gallery photos. Hope that helps....